# Isn't a semialgebra an algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I was solving this exercise in a book, "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory", by Jeffrey Rosenthal.

Exercise 2.7.3. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a 
collection of subsets of $\Omega$, such that
$\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$.
b) Assume $\mathcal{F}$ is a semialgebra. 
Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra.

However, it seems to me this exercise is wrong. 
A counterexample suffices to show it.
Suppose a set  $\mathcal{J}$ of all intervals in $[0,1]$. Then, it is easy
to show that $\mathcal{J}$ is a semi-algebra. Suppose two different
intervals $A = [0,\frac{1}{3}]$ and $B = [\frac{2}{3},1]$ are present in 
$\mathcal{J}$. $A \cup B$ does not belong to $\mathcal{J}$ because it is not an interval. $\mathcal{J}$ is not an algebra because
it is not closed under finite unions.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Which book are you referring to? It might be helpful for others to know. Please include the details in an [edit].

Comment: What is your definition of "semialgebra"?

Comment: @EricWofsey algebra would be the same, but accepting it is closed under complement and under finite union.

Comment: That's not the standard definition of semi-algebra. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Basic_Structures_And_Definitions/Semialgebras,_Algebras_and_σ-algebras

Comment: @JoelPereira I made a mistake, the book uses the same definition. But the question remains.

Comment: @AlexVong you're right. im deleting that last comment.

Comment: @DunhoClark Is there a part a) to your question? Is there more conditions on $\mathcal{F}$, or $\Omega$?

Comment: @JoelPereira Part a) is independent. "(a) Suppose that whenever $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$,
then also $A \setminus B \equiv A \cap B^c \in \mathcal{F}$.
Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra."